# Why is the type of "Banana with Cream" the same as "Banana" after erasure ? How can it be fixed?

Tags: scala

I want different method binding (at compile-time !) depending on a marker trait (like `Cream`). How can this be achieved ?

My solution below does not compile.

How can it be fixed ?

```
class Apple
class Banana
trait Cream

object HasOverloadedMethods
{
  def method(p:Apple)=println("Apple")
  def method(p:Banana)=println("Banana")
  def method(p:Banana with Cream)=println("Banana with Cream")
}

object Question extends App{
  HasOverloadedMethods.method(new Apple())
  HasOverloadedMethods.method(new Banana())
  HasOverloadedMethods.method(new Banana() with Cream)
}
```

error:

```
double definition:
method method:(p: Banana with Cream)Unit and
method method:(p: Banana)Unit at line 9
have same type after erasure: (p: Banana)Unit
  def method(p:Banana with Cream)=println("Banana with Cream")
      ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't fix it like that, since the JVM doesn't know mixin types (and the bytecode signature of `method(x: Banana with Cream)` is therefore only `method(x: Banana)`).

You have a couple of options, which all have their drawbacks.

1. Only take a `Cream`. This makes you loose the `Banana`
2. Create a `BananaWithCream` trait. This clutters your hierarchy.
3. Use type-classes:

   ```
   def method[T : MethImpl](x: T) = implicitly[MethImpl[T]].impl(x)

   trait MethImpl[T] {
     def impl(x: T): Unit
   }

   trait LowPrioMethImpl {
     implicit object BananaImpl extends MethImpl[Banana] {
       def impl(x: Banana) = println("Banana")
     }
   }

   object MethImpl extends LowPrioMethImpl {
     implicit object AppleImpl extends MethImpl[Apple] {
       def impl(x: Apple) = println("Apple")
     }

     implicit object BananaWithCreamImpl extends MethImpl[Banana with Cream] {
       def impl(x: Banana with Cream) = println("Banana with Cream")
     }
   }
   ```

   Now you can:

   ```
   method(new Banana) // > Banana
   method(new Banana with Cream) // > Banana with Cream
   method(new Apple) // > Apple

   method("adsf") // error: Could not find implicit value ...
   ```

   The con is obviously the clutter this solution introduces.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! May I kindly ask you to edit the code example in such a way that it can be pasted into a .scala file, compiled and executed ? I am currently trying to do that but I have difficulty figuring out where to put what.

Comment: One problem I am facing when I am trying to make your code example work is that in `def impl(x: T) = println("Apple")` the `T` cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

After a good night sleep I woke up with this solution in my head :)

```
class Apple
class Banana

trait IceCream


object HasOverloadedMethods
{
  def method(p:Apple)=println("Apple")
  def method(p:Banana)=println("Banana")
  def method[T<:Banana with IceCream](p:T)
     (implicit ev:T<:<Banana with IceCream)= println("Banana with IceCream")
}

object Question extends App{
  HasOverloadedMethods.method(new Apple())
  HasOverloadedMethods.method(new Banana())
  HasOverloadedMethods.method(new Banana() with IceCream)
}
```

Prints:

```
Apple
Banana
Banana with IceCream
```